# Azure Mobile Apps - Table Middleware

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with a node app for Azure Mobile Apps.

I have an Easy Table with a read operation that looks something like this:

```
table.read(function (context) {
  context.query.where({ _user_id: context.req.userId });
  return context.execute();
});
```

Now I want to add some middleware before that function runs which adds userId into the req, and so I thought I was supposed to do something like this:

```
table.use((req,res,next) => {
  req.userId = "1234";
  next();
}, table.operation);
```

Now, inside the `table.read`, if i `console.log(context.req.userId)` it comes out correct, but for some reason after adding thing `.use`, `context.query` becomes undefined. When I take off `table.use`, `context.query.where({ _user_id: "1234" })` works perfectly.

How am I supposed to do this middleware properly within Azure Mobile Apps? Why is defining `table.use` messing with `context.query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the middleware at the application level instead:

```
mobileApp.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.userId = "1234";
    next();
});
mobileApp.tables.import('./tables');
mobileApp.api.import('./api');
```

Comment: I will definitely try that, thank you my dude. Will get back to you hopefully tonight after work with my attempt

Comment: I actually ended up going with a very different route because i discovered that when i was calling `table.use`, the function actually wasn't even defined yet. Your answer would have solved that issue as well, so thank you.